# "CLUSTER BY expression must be groupable, but type is STRUCT" error

Tags: google-bigquery

I've created a table using the web UI as:

```
create table `project.dataset.test3` as (select 123 as id, 456 as offer_id)
```

I want to create a clustered table from the previously created table so I try:

```
create table `project.dataset.test4` partition by (fake_date) 
cluster by (id, offer_id) as (
SELECT current_timestamp() fake_date, id, offer_id
FROM `project.dataset.test3`
group by 1,2,3)
```

But I get the error message:

```
CLUSTER BY expression must be groupable, but type is STRUCT at [2:12]
```

I searched the documentation but was unable to get any insight into this error message or formulate any way around it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting parentheses around two or more comma-separated expressions creates a struct, and in the statement you provided, you have:

```
cluster by (id, offer_id)
```

If you remove the parentheses, the statement should succeed:

```
cluster by id, offer_id
```

Comment: Just to add some more context for @DimJim, here you can find [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#clustering_column_list) explaining that `clustering_column_list` should be a comma-separated list, no parenthesis required. Additionally, in this other page there is [an example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-clustered-tables#sample_table_used_in_the_examples) where clustering is performed on different columns without using parenthesis.